# Is there a better way to do drop down menues in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use jQuery's `hover` to do drop down menues.  So the first thing I try is:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>

$(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none", visibility: "hidden"});
$(" #menu li ").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first:hidden').css(visibility:"visible", display:"block"}).show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"hidden", display:"none"});
  });
```

and this works great... in Firefox.  Unfortunately in the version of Chrome I'm running (9.0.597.94) if you mouse over that drop down menu it fires the mouse out on $("#menu li#).

So ok, we have a race condition, all I need to do is add some timers...

```
(function(){
var timer;
$(" #menu li ").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first:hidden').css(visibility:"visible", display:"block"}).show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    var header = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        header.find('ul:first').css({visibility:"hidden", display:"none"});
      }, 100);
  });
$(" #menu li > ul ").hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css({visibility:"hidden", display:"none"});
  });
}();
```

Which works real great, until someone says `we need to put a textbox in that dropdown menu`; and of course a text box causes the mouse out to fire on $(" #menu li > ul "), so now I've got to put another nested layer of timers and I'm thinking to myself: **There has got to be a better way to do this**!

So I was hoping someone could clue me in...

Comment: Question #1: Why do you need a text box in a menu?

Comment: @Paulo you can safely assume all "design" decisions are happening at a level I have 0 control over.  However, this is a recurring problem for me (drop down menus and timeouts) and it would be nice if there was just an easier way for me to create these menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use [Suckerfish](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) (or to be sophistimacated [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/))?  It seems like this is a wheel that needn't be reinvented...

Comment: I definitely want to stop reinventing the wheel, and I liked the idea behind Suckerfish (adding state to the DOM instead of the JS); but is there a way I can apply that approach to all decedents? Right now it only goes to children and I need children of children (and so on...).

Comment: Do you want all of the descendants to open out when you click on a parent?  Or would you like the ability to progress down one layer at a time?  Here's an example of the latter in superfish: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#a  The former would require a little extra stripting...

Comment: definitely the former.  The issue I'm specifically having is that some of the children of children are triggering mouseout on parent

Comment: Sorry now I'm confused.  How many layers deep are your nested lists?  Are you sure what you want isn't handled by the example I pointed to? (By the way I didn't have the has on the URL right - http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples).

Answer (score 2):

Anyway... I guess you can take a look here: [38 jQuery and CSS Drop Down Multi Level Menu Solutions](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/).

Comment: I got through the first dozen of these without any help for my use case.  Do you think you could be more specific?